# AtUnit and guice module overrides

Tags: guice, atunit

I would like to use

```
Module functionalTestModule
    = Modules.override(new ProductionModule()).with(new TestModule());
```

for test cases so I can inherit all the production bindings and just override them for tests(replacing instances with mocks).  Is there a way to do this with AtUnit.  The implementing Module seems weird in the design since I would think we would want to just inherit all production bindings and mock the ones needed, but maybe there is a second way of doing other than having the test implement Module.

Maybe there is a way to annotate AtUnit telling AtUnit the production module in the test case and then having configure in the test case that gets the TestModule overrides?  is there such a way?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know anything about AtUnit, but a quick look at it makes it look like you just implement `Module` in your test. I don't know if there's some other way of doing it, but following those rules you could just do:

```
public class SomeTest implements Module {
  public void configure(Binder binder) {
    binder.install(Modules.override(new ProductionModule()).with(new TestModule()));
  }
}
```